# How to get MVC3 Area Exception was hit in using ELMAH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, elmah, area

We are trying to email different people based on what area an exception was hit in using ELMAH.  We have everything working, except the ability to figure out what area an exception was hit in.  Is there an easy way to get the string representing the MVC3 Area where an exception was initially thrown from within ELMAH?

Essentially, we want what would be returned by `controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] as string` but don't know how to get the controllerContext from within Elmah.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Elmah knows anything about which controller triggered the initial exception.

One way you can solve this problem, however, is to add the AREA name to the Request Cache on every Request.  Once it's there, assuming the exception happens after you put it there, you should be able to fetch it.